# Should I remove -fobjc-arc flag when convert to ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I was wanted to convert my project to ARC which is using partial files in ARC already. They are using -fobjc-arc flags in build phases, and I did refactoring(Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC) but those flags are still remained in Build Phase.

What I am not clear here,

- When I refactor project to ARC, the project is changing to ARC mode or just the code in class files(.m) are changing to ARC type?

Anybody experiencing this, advice is great help to me

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this answer. It's doing both, changing target to ARC as well as code to ARC but not converting -fobjc-arc flag at build phase